# How do I update a key value of JSON file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, fs

I have below JSON in which I want to update Test1 object values.
My requirement is that after 1 hour, I have to generate new token and update access_token, time_updated and time_created in Test1 object. Rest things must be same.
I don't want to change anything except Test1 object.

Please help me. It would be a great favour for me.

Thank you

```
{
   "Test1":{
        "type" : "type",
        "client_id": "xyz",
        "client_secret": "xyz",
        "grant_type": "av",
        "token_uri": "url",
        "resource":"resource",
        "access_token" : "",
        "time_created":2342524,
        "time_updated":1612251593
    },

     "Test2":{
        "type" : "type",
        "client_id": "xyz",
        "client_secret": "xyz",
        "grant_type": "av",
        "token_uri": "url",
        "resource":"resource",
        "access_token" : "",
        "time_created":2342524,
        "time_updated":1612251593
    }
}
```

Comment: One interesting issue with node js fs module which I found is
when I am trying to read json file from the same directory( fs.readFileSync('./filename.json')) where my code logic file is, it works fine, JSON.parse() gives me JS object and I can access keys but when JSON file is outside directory of my code logic file( say fs.readFileSync('../filename.json') ), JSON.parse() returns string. Is it problem with fs or I am facing this. I am using Typescript.

Comment: I don't think fs has anything to do with it, it sounds more like your other JSON file's contents were stringified twice. This is just guesswork though, you would have to show us the code and the exact contents of the JSON file to troubleshoot it. Also you didn't mention _what_ string you get.

Comment: So, is this a backend process that is only using Node.js? Or are you using this in a browser? This matters as there are Web APIs available in the browser that are not available in Node.js. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38367036/nodejs-api-vs-javascript-web-apis-interfaces

Comment: I used require() to import JSON and it worked but it has it's own downside.                                  @CherryDT, my exact JSON contains critical credentials which I can't share publicly. I don't think, you understood my requirements properly. I am asking to update a particular key of JSON not writing in whole file again. Because if I do so wherever I am going to use this code( say I build a npm package of it and installed in some other project), it will create JSON file there as well as soon as I call this functionality which I don't want.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you just wrote. Aren't those two the same thing? To update a single key you have to read the whole file, update the key in memory and write the whole file back. About the credentials, you could just replace the secrets with dummy text (only the actual values, not any keys or part of the syntax), I'm more interested in the structure. And in regards to your last point it makes no sense to me either - if you would call it in a project without the file it would crash, not create anything, but then I don't know why you'd even call it there if there is no data to change

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
var  data = {
   "Test1":{
        "type" : "type",
        "client_id": "xyz",
        "client_secret": "xyz",
        "grant_type": "av",
        "token_uri": "url",
        "resource":"resource",
        "access_token" : "",
        "time_created":2342524,
        "time_updated":1612251593
    },

     "Test2":{
        "type" : "type",
        "client_id": "xyz",
        "client_secret": "xyz",
        "grant_type": "av",
        "token_uri": "url",
        "resource":"resource",
        "access_token" : "",
        "time_created":2342524,
        "time_updated":1612251593
    }
};

Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if(key === "Test1"){     
     data[key].time_created = "NewValue";
     }
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Bharat, this is okay but my problem is I am reading JSON file 
from some other directory and that's where fs or any file system npm module gives me problem in Typescript. JSON.parse() gives me string not JavaScript object which is quite strange. Please check my above comment too.

Comment: even if it's string Object.entries should give you object that you can process

Answer (score 1):

As JSON is technically a string, I am assuming that you are wanting to take a JSON string and change the data inside it, all while keeping is as a string.

First you would need to convert it to a JavaScript Object. Once it is an Object, then you can just use dot notation into the object to change the values that you want.

Lastly, you would convert that JavaScript Object back into a JSON string.

Of course, if you are referring to a JavaScript Object and not a JSON string, then you would just need to use the dot notation to change the values.

See snippet below.

```js
let jsonString = `{
   "Test1":{
        "type" : "type",
        "client_id": "xyz",
        "client_secret": "xyz",
        "grant_type": "av",
        "token_uri": "url",
        "resource":"resource",
        "access_token" : "",
        "time_created":2342524,
        "time_updated":1612251593
    },

     "Test2":{
        "type" : "type",
        "client_id": "xyz",
        "client_secret": "xyz",
        "grant_type": "av",
        "token_uri": "url",
        "resource":"resource",
        "access_token" : "",
        "time_created":2342524,
        "time_updated":1612251593
    }
}`;



function updateJson() {

  //Convert the JSON string to a JavaScript Object
  const jsObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);

  //Set the value using dot notation.
  //I just set some random values for the example
  //You would insert your values here: 
  jsObject.Test1.access_token = btoa((Math.random() * 100) ** 10);
  jsObject.Test1.time_created = Math.random() * 100;
  jsObject.Test1.time_updated = Date.parse(new Date()) / 1000;

  //Convert the JavaScript Object back into a JSON string
  jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsObject, null, 2);

  console.log(jsonString)
}
```

```css
button {
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="updateJson()">Click to Update</button>
```

Comment: Steve, this is okay but my problem is I am reading JSON file 
from some other directory and that's where fs module or any file system npm module gives me problem in Typescript. JSON.parse() gives me string not JavaScript object which is quite strange. Please check my above comment too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that might guide you to your purpose.
Firstly, you have to be familiar with JSON data such as how to access/modify an element in JSON. The first parts of the code below introduce some general idea of accessing and modifying JSON.

The second part is  about how to trigger a function every x sec with the setTimeout() function.

```js
let mydata= {
  "Test1":{
       "type" : "type",
       "client_id": "xyz",
       "client_secret": "xyz",
       "grant_type": "av",
       "token_uri": "url",
       "resource":"resource",
       "access_token" : "",
       "time_created":2342524,
       "time_updated":1612251593
   },

    "Test2":{
       "type" : "type",
       "client_id": "xyz",
       "client_secret": "xyz",
       "grant_type": "av",
       "token_uri": "url",
       "resource":"resource",
       "access_token" : "",
       "time_created":2342524,
       "time_updated":1612251593
   }
}

//This part shows how to access to JSON data
console.log(mydata.Test1.time_created);
console.log(mydata.Test1.time_updated);

mydata.Test1.time_created = 01;
mydata.Test1.time_updated = 02;

console.log(mydata.Test1.time_created);
console.log(mydata.Test1.time_updated);

console.log(typeof mydata.Test1.time_created);
console.log(typeof mydata.Test1.time_updated);

console.log(mydata.Test1);


//This part shows how to trigger doAThingEveryHour 
function doAThingEveryHour() {
  setTimeout(doAThingEveryHour,5*1000)//Trigger doAThingEveryHour  every 5s
  mydata.Test1.time_updated = Date.now();
  console.log("timeUpdate:" + mydata.Test1.time_updated);
}
setTimeout(doAThingEveryHour,5*1000)
```

Comment: this is okay but my problem is I am reading JSON file 
from some other directory and that's where fs or any file system npm module gives me problem in Typescript. JSON.parse() gives me string not JavaScript object which is quite strange. Please check my above comment too.